How to solve automation error in vba code to create OHLC chart?
I am trying to create a OHLC stock chart on a sheet called "Chart" with data located on a sheet called "ChartData"
I get an automation error at the line:
Set OHLCChart = ws1.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G2").Left, Width:=400, Top:=Range("G2").Top, Height:=250)
Thank you in advance for your help.
Here is the full code:
Sub CreateCandlestick()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim nRows As Long
    Dim ch As ChartObject

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ChartData")

    'Delete existing charts

    For Each ch In ws1.ChartObjects
        ch.Delete
    Next

    nRows = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Create candlestick chart

    Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject
    Set OHLCChart = ws1.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("G2").Left, Width:=400, Top:=Range("G2").Top, Height:=250)

    With OHLCChart.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=ws2.Range("A1:E" & nRows)
        .ChartType = xlStockOHLC
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Candlestick Chart for " & ws1.Range("ticker")
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Price"
        .HasLegend = False
        .PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 230, 241)
        .ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Parent.Name = "OHLC Chart"
    End With
End Sub


Always qualify the range object with a specified sheet. Try Set OHLCChart = ws1.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ws1.Range("G2").Left, Width:=400, Top:=ws1.Range("G2").Top, Height:=250).

Just tried but it still gives the automation error

What's the error number and which line?

Always give full details of the error - in this case Run-time error '-1328086641 (b0d7018f)': Automation error . I am getting the same error but on the line .ChartType = xlStockOHLC - are you absolutely sure you have given us the correct line causing the problem?
If I change the ChartType to be xlColumnStacked then there is no issue so I can only assume that you haven't supplied sufficient information for a ChartType of xlStockOHLC

The full error is indeed Run-time error '-1328086641 (b0d7018f)': Automation error. When I click debug vba highlights in yellow the line I indicated so I assumed that is where the problem is. If I change the chart type to xlColumnStacked to try it still gives the same automation error and points to the same line causing the problem

The line that gives the error is Set OHLCChart = ws1.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ws1.Range("G2").Left, Width:=400, Top:=ws1.Range("G2").Top, Height:=250)

I changed the default chart type to a line chart and ran the code again. The automation error is gone but now I have the error Run-time error '-1328086641 (b0d7018f)': The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type on the line .ChartType = xlStockOHLC

I changed the line nRows = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count to avoid using UsedRange. The new code is nRows = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row This solves the issue and I can create the OHLC chart properly now. Thank you all for the support :)

It might help to set PlotBy... .SetSourceData Source:=ws2.Range("A1:E" & nRows), PlotBy:=xlColumns
